# Gaze library properties not found in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, properties, uwp, nuget

Visual Studio doesn't seem to recognize some properties that are crucial to make gaze tracking work. On my XAML page (I have an UWP app), I have the following code.

```
<Page
x:Class="App14.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App14"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:g="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Input.GazeInteraction"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
g:GazeInput.Interaction="Enabled"
g:GazeInput.IsCursorVisible="True"
g:GazeInput.CursorRadius="20"
g:GazeInput.IsSwitchEnabled="False">
</Page>
```

However, Visual Studio doesn't recognize the properties `g:GazeInput.Interaction="Enabled"`, `g:GazeInput.IsCursorVisible="True"`, `g:GazeInput.CursorRadius="20"` and `g:GazeInput.IsSwitchEnabled="False">`

These properties are underlined in green saying that these properties are failed to be found in `Microsoft.Toolkit.UWP.Input.GazeInteraction.GazeInput.*insert property here*`.

I've installed the NuGet package for Gaze from Microsoft and my Windows 10 version is 1803 (Build 17134).

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you clarify what are your projects target and min version? (check in project properties). I think the min version needs to be at least 17134 as well.

Comment: Hello Stefan! Thanks for your response! Target is the same as for minimum version, so both are on 17134.

Comment: Does it repro with a new, empty project created from scratch? Can you share a repro project. Asking because I can't reproduce the error here.

Comment: Yes, it does get reproduced even if I open a new project. Here's the link to the project (I uploaded it to mediafire) https://www.mediafire.com/file/dfju95s8eqy18u3/App14.zip/file

Comment: Sorry, I used an earlier version of the app. Here's the updated one: http://www.mediafire.com/file/185fa2ui5au3v33/App14.zip/file Thanks again for looking into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried out your sample project and indeed it didn't compile the first time. However, the references and project version targets were properly set so it means Visual Studio did not pick up the NuGet packages properly for some reason.

If you open up the **References** node in Solution Explorer, you should see the following:

[image: References]

If you don't see the two blue NuGet package items in the list, you need to force Visual Studio to install them.

First right-click the solution in **Solution Explorer** and select **Restore NuGet Packages for Solution...**. This will take a while and Visual Studio should download the missing packages. If they don't appear in the **References** list (in my case they still didn't), close and reopen Visual Studio. This fixed the references and I could successfully compile the app.

If not, you can try the following:

1. Close Visual Studio, go to your project folder and delete **obj** and **bin** folders. Open Visual Studio again and see if it helped.
2. Uninstall and re-install the NuGet package for Gaze.
3. Force-reinstall NuGet packages (see my [article](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2018/02/tip-force-reinstall-nuget-packages/) or below). Close and reopen Visual Studio.

In Package Manager Console write:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

One of these steps should hopefully fix your issue and make the app compile.

Comment: So this did make sure it is recognized now and it looks like everything is working fine, but when I deploy the app, I do not see any cursor to indicate where my eyes are gazing at. I know there could be a million reasons as to why that is happening, but I still think this has still something to do with the original issue of VS not detecting the property. Thanks a lot for helping me though!

Comment: I think that is probably a different issue, as it has different symptoms and now the property is definitely compiled in the resulting app. Consider opening a new question for this and going through the Gaze documentation if you haven't left out some step. Also please consider marking this question as resolved so that it is closed :-)

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to fix it by just simply making sure Gaze tracing was enabled in the capabilities section. Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: Glad it helped :-) Hope I will see your gaze enabled app in Store :-) !

Comment: It’s for a school project that analyses dyslexia through eye tracking. Don’t really see it actually going to get released in store but we’ll never know ;)